# Azure two VM's in cloud service, can not RDP to one

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and trying to setup our companies testing environment in Azure.

As I understand it for two machines to talk to each other in Azure they need to be in the same cloud service, i.e. our web server and DB server.

So I have created a service, then created each of the VM's in that service.  They are both running.  In the endpoints I can see:

web server:

```
NAME           PROTOCOL  PUBLIC PORT  PRIVATE PORT  LOAD-BALANCED SET NAME
HTTP           TCP       80           80             -
HTTPS          TCP       443          443            -
PowerShell     TCP       5986         5986           -
Remote Desktop TCP       50232        3389           -
```

db server:

```
NAME           PROTOCOL       PUBLIC PORT  PRIVATE PORT LOAD-BALANCED SET NAME
MSSQL          TCP            1433         1433          -
PowerShell     TCP            54327        5986          -
Remote Desktop TCP            52459        3389          -
```

in the cloud service the input areas

```
INPUT ENDPOINTS
protoApp : 123.456.789.227:80
protoApp : 123.456.789.227:443
protoApp : 123.456.789.227:5986
protoApp : 123.456.789.227:50232
protodb : 123.456.789.227:1433
protodb : 123.456.789.227:54327
protodb : 123.456.789.227:52459
```

I can connect to the protodb server but not the protoapp server (on the given ports).

There are two  / three questions really.

1. Should they both be in the same cloud service?
2. Should the live DB and web server be in a seperate cloud server (not created them yet)
3. Can anyone think of a reason why I can no longer MSTSC / rdp to one of the machines, even though the endpoints say its all fine, the machine is running and the cloud service says it has it as an endpoint.

Comment: And have you tried connecting first to the DB Server and from it RDP to the APP server. Normally the setup you created should work. Don't know what is going on. But, the general advice is to use Azure Virtual  Network to connect VMs. That way you will also be able to establish VPN tunnel directly from on-premises to Azure and RDP to the VMs using local Addressing without going to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

1. No reason why not, though you should look at creating a Virtual Network to connect them
2. You should consider this if

   - Performance dictates it
   - You want extra security - consider somebody hacks the web server, they then immediately have access to the same server that hosts the data. Really you should restrict the incoming IPs for MSSQL to something trusted anyway, or the same subnet if you use a Virtual Network
   - Cost is not an issue
3. I've sometimes had trouble using `mstsc` to directly connect via RDP to Azure VMs. If you go to http://manage.windowsazure.com and navigate to your VM, there will be a "Connect" option at the bottom. This will download a `.rdp` file which might help.

Something else worth noting, If you're using Azure VMs, you won't qualify for Microsoft's uptime SLA unless you have two or more VMs per cloud service configured as part of an **Availability Set**. So straight away you should consider that the number of VMs you're planning will double if you want to have a production/highly available environment, and you should consider the impact this will have on your application architecture too.